# How to get more error details in Apache Drill

Tags: sql, apache-drill

### Is there any way how to get more details from SQL errors?

Speaking in terms of data-related errors, drill does not give any clue where and how to find the issue. SQL syntax and logic errors are rendered somewhat comprehensible, but imagine these cases:

#### Classic example

You have ~10GB CSV full of numbers (*sales.csv*):

```
ArticleId,CategoryId,Price,SupplierPrice,VAT
1234,23,15.19,12.45,0
1235,23,16.19,13.45,0.15
...
[83541670] lines
...
475,34.0,55.0,50,0.15  # This random error cause (CategoryId should be INT for this example)
...
[34767806] lines
...
[EOF]
```

Then consider a similar query:

```sql
SELECT 
 CAST (ArticleId as INT) as ArticleId,
 CAST (CategoryId as INT) as CategoryId,
 CAST (Price as DOUBLE) as Price,
 CAST (SupplierPrice as double) as SupplierPrice,
 CAST (VAT as DOUBLE) as VAT
from (...)/sales.csv
```

**And you got this error:**

```sql
SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: 
Fragment 0:0
Please, refer to logs for more information.
```

Well, referring to logs:

```
[Error Id: 682cc450-61fb-4307-809a-fcb794fec692 on drill-staging-745f9968d4-m5pv7:31010]
    at org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:630) ~[drill-common-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.sendFinalState(FragmentExecutor.java:363) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.cleanup(FragmentExecutor.java:219) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run(FragmentExecutor.java:329) [drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run(SelfCleaningRunnable.java:38) [drill-common-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111-internal]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    at org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.StringFunctionHelpers.nfeI(StringFunctionHelpers.java:96) ~[drill-java-exec-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
[...continues with hundred similar lines ...]
```

### The problem

- You don't know *what* happened, only that it has to do something with some number.
- You don't know *where* that happened
- When referring to logs, there is no useful information
- It happens *often*.
- Investigating these errors takes huge amount of time, because every time, you have to go through hundred millions lines and search the error by some work-around approximation queries.
- Using drill for data-cleaning makes it impossible just for these reasons. We would have to use another big-data solution and at this point we wouldn't have to use Drill at all.

### Questions

- Is there *any* option to increase verbosity?
- Aren't there any other logs / sources where to get error detail?
- Is there any useful workaround how to handle these situations while not ruining the performance? (There are many combinations, ie '' instead of null and vice versa, wrong datatype for number, too many decimal places for a decimal, ...)

When it would be so beautiful when Drill would give us errors like ...:

```sql
ERROR casting column "Price" to Int - Invalid integer value "34.0"
```

Comment: Which version of Drill are you using? New Text v3 reader was introduced since 1.15 (it is default text reader since 1.16). It fixed numerous text reader errors, has better error descriptions and also gives possibility to enforce schema - https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-or-replace-schema/

Comment: Currently we're using drill 1.16

Comment: Try to use instead of casts schema file (see the link above).

Comment: @ArinaYelchiyeva Works well, big thanks for the DATA_READ ERROR. Would you please create an answer from this so I could close this question?

Comment: Sure, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast operation is applied after data was read thus at this point Drill does not have information from where in file incorrect data came from. Since Drill 1.16 schema provisioning support was introduced. Table schema is applied during data read, so Drill can produce better error messages (`DATA_READ_ERROR`). For more information see https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-or-replace-schema/.